# TypeScript type inference with lookup types and switch case

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, type-inference

I have following TypeScript code:

```
type Test = {
    a: string;
    b: boolean;
    c: number;
}
const instance: Test = {
    a: 'a',
    b: true,
    c: 2,
}

function getValue<T extends keyof Test>(val: T): Test[T] {
    return instance[val];
}

function setValue<T extends keyof Test>(key: T, value: Test[T]): void {
    instance[key] = value;

    onChangeValue(key, value);
}

function onChangeValue<T extends keyof Test>(key: T, value: Test[T]): void {
    switch (key) {
        case 'a':
            let a: string = value; // why TS won't infer that value must be type Test['a'] ie. string? Is there any way to fix it?
        break;
        case 'b':
            let b: boolean = value;
        break;
        case 'c':
            let c: number = value;
        break
    }
}

let d: number = getValue('c'); // works fine

setValue('a', 'fsdfdsf'); // works fine
```

So basically I have methods which accept one argument which is key in object(type) and second is value to set value of that key in object. I'm using here lookup types based on value of passed key. It is working fine for usage of method which returns value based on key, and sets value based on key. However I have third function `onChangeValue` inside of which I want to recognize type of value parameter based on type of key parameter. Why it doesn't work here? Why compiler won't correctly infer type of value parameter? Is there any way to fix it and make it work without explicit type casting?

Comment: Your `setValue` is working exactly as it should as the key `a` exists on `Test` and 'fsdfdsf' is a string. I don't understand what the problem is.

Comment: Function `onChangeValue` is not working as I described.

Comment: `onChangeValue` does not use `getValue` or `setValue` it simply takes in the input 'a' and 'fsdfdsf'. Since 'a' is already a key of `instance` it simply updates the value. I'm not sure from the provided code how `onChangeValue` is called but it also wouldn't fail because 'a' is a valid key and 'fsdfdsf' is a string. What happens if you call it like `setValue('x', 'fsdfdsf')`

Comment: The type inference is not done in the switch case, even though the cases are narrowing. For example, in the case C, the method `toFixed` can not be used because it's still inferred as `boolean | number | string`

Comment: Not an exact duplicate, but this question and especially the anwer to it might help you:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60996253/infer-typescript-function-return-type-from-enum-parameter

Comment: This fixes onChange but moves assertion to setValue https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKhDOwoF4oG8oEMBcVECcBLAOwHMBuKAI1yoHs6AbCTYygY12IFcBbKiPkoBfAFDs6xRFBKJW7CLjjTUGHFADkmDQBpquYPm4Q9nKACYdY0QDNuxdsEKS8EYADVMjYwB4YUCAAPYAhiABN4KABrCBA6G1gEYAA+AAoYkCU9ADcvYyUkgG0YAF0ASlxsukIw9FEoBpkpYHkIQoySlChc7whyUXrGyQBhAAtWUghPXvTYnLzoTEjWEDL+61BIWG4wZng-ZK6MQoAFJujY+NgS3HbY3BP53qVTks7hO7iE0oG7BycXCNxmQpgtUgA6SGfJ7GG7bXYIPxJZIVbrVWpoQYNeAAd0IwHYoygs1WdUa5Kg7CW0C0GmwWIp5OYSHUBBIpC6PWM-UZDSo+BYUR5vKp8BpVDpDN5UGZ+moDGYrE5C2FjP5gtVFNFNPYkulTLclK4fAE+GVvU15PVmCiDLEYjFHjBtL0Ghs8DCNgiNg0aygQA

Comment: This compiles: `onChangeValue(Math.random() < 0.99 ? "a" : "c", 123);` which is why the implementation has errors... you can't guarantee that `T` extends only a type which is only *one* key of `Test`.  It could be the full `keyof Test` and therefore maybe the two parameters are from different properties.  You really want something like [ms/TS#27808](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27808) but it's not part of the language currently.  As far as I know you can refactor to either have `switch`-style code work *or* have non-switch code work, but not both (without assertions). ...

Comment: ... does that fully address your question? Do you want me to write up an answer?  Or am I missing something?

Comment: @jcalz it does answer it to some degree. I understand that T can be any subset keyof Test, including any combination of union keys. But I thought that's where switch case should come in, and compiler should correctly narrow type here (because in single switch case block it's obvious that first function parameter can be only one precise type). I guess correct answer is just "it works like that".

Comment: @Titian Cernicova-Dragomir
This is an excellent suggestion, with help of it I found full solution to fix my case. Please post it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @jcalz pointed out in their comment, the type of `onChangeValue` doesn't mean that the type of `value` is a specific type.

For example, when you declare a constant `k` like this, its type becomes `'a' | 'b'`.

```
const k: 'a' | 'b' = true ? 'a' : 'b' as const
```

Then when you call `onChangeValue` with `k`, `onChangeValue` will be instantiated as `function onChangeValue<'a' | 'b'>(key: 'a' | 'b', value: string | boolean): void`.

```
onChangeValue(k, true);
```

As you can see, even though `key` is `'a'`, `value` can be `boolean`. That's why the compiler doesn't narrow the type of `value` in the `switch`.